# How to find the longest substring by order of frequency?

Tags: c#

This is best described with an example.  Given the paragraph:

`The longest string in this paragraph is not the shortest string in the paragraph because it is the longest string in the paragraph`

I want to list the order of matching sub-strings first by frequency and then by length, so in this case, it should list (non case-sensitive)

- `The longest string in`
- `the paragraph`
- `is not the shortest string in`
- `because`
- `it is`
- `this`

The above lists the substrings by the order of frequency they occur, followed by length, so `The longest string in` is repeated twice and is the longest substring.  `is not the shortest string in` is longer than `the paragraph`, but `the paragraph` is repeated twice, so it is listed first.

Update(based on observation by AlexC and MattBurland):

Even if a sub-string such as the space character or `in` occur more than other substrings, they should not be listed if they are already included in a substring that is longer than their occurrence * length.  For example,  `in` occurs 3 times which is 6 characters in length (9 including spaces at the end), but since 9 characters is shorter than `the paragraph`, it is not listed.  I hope this makes sense?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem

Comment: @MattBurland - Ah, nice catch, you have a good point.  I guess I should rephrase the question.  If `in` x 3 is greater than another substring x n, then `in` should be listed first.  Does that make sense? BUT, if in is already included in a substring that is longer than in * occurences, it should not be listed.

Comment: I don't think you are looking for substrings as the substring ' ' would be the most common followed by 'i'.  It sounds like you are looking for whole words / combinations of words.

Comment: @AlexC - I think you may be correct, I might just have trouble saying it correctly.  I updated my post, let me know if that makes sense with the update.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, like the others said, if you extract the substrings from the example you provided and trim the blank spaces, you will get an array of string such as this:

string[] myArray = {"the" , "longest", .... etc

now, what you could do is loop into the array remove the string that are similar while increasing their occurrence. You then add this info into a list.

Then you loop again to order them by length. But still, at the end, the strings that will be in the list can't be a combinations of words, except if the input string are separated by something else than a space at first like a $ sign.

"The longest string in$ this paragraph $is not the shortest string in $the paragraph$ because it is$ the longest string in $the paragraph"

if that's the case, you just do exactly the same procedure as above but separate the substrings by $ sign instead of space.